# How to ignore old messages sent when the bot was offline in ruby?

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot, ruby-on-rails-7

Let's say I have a very simple bot

```
require 'telegram/bot'

Telegram::Bot::Client.run(ENV['TOKEN']) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    case message.text
    when '/start'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Hello!')
    when '/stop'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Goodbye!')
    when 'Hi'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Hello')
    end
  end
end
```

And someone spammed Hi & start & stop in the group chat while the bot was offline, how can I make the bot ignore all the messages that was sent when it was offline? Knowing that there's no database to store when it came back alive.

Comment: Seems fairly easy: compare the message's timestamp to the time your bot was (re-)started.